# Cannot load int variable from previous session in tensorflow 1.1

Tags: variables, tensorflow, save, load, restore

I have read many similar questions and just cannot get this to work properly.

I have my model being trained well and checkpoint files are being made every epoch. I want to have it so the program can continue from epoch x once reloaded and also for it to print that is on that epoch with every iteration. I could simply save the data outside of the checkpoint file, however I was also wanting to do this to give me confidence everything else is also being stored properly.

Unfortunately the value in the epoch/global_step variable is always still 0 when I restart.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# more imports


def extract_number(f): # used to get latest checkpint file
    s = re.findall("epoch(\d+).ckpt",f)
    return (int(s[0]) if s else -1,f)

def restore(init_op, sess, saver): # called to restore or just initialise model
    list = glob(os.path.join("./params/e*"))

    if list:

        file = max(list,key=extract_number)

        saver.restore(sess, file[:-5])


    sess.run(init_op)
    return


with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:

    # build models


    total_batch = data.train.num_examples / batch_size

    epochLimit = 51

    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()


    with tf.Session() as sess:


        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        restore(init_op, sess, saver)


        epoch = global_step.eval()


        while epoch < epochLimit:

            total_batch = data.train.num_examples / batch_size

            for i in range(int(total_batch)):

                sys.stdout.flush()

                voxels = newData.eval()

                batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [batch_size, z_size]).astype(np.float32)

                sess.run(opt_G, feed_dict={z:batch_z, train:True})
                sess.run(opt_D, feed_dict={input:voxels, z:batch_z, train:True})


                with open("out/loss.csv", 'a') as f:
                    batch_loss_G = sess.run(loss_G, feed_dict={z:batch_z, train:False})
                    batch_loss_D = sess.run(loss_D, feed_dict={input:voxels, z:batch_z, train:False})
                    msgOut = "Epoch: [{0}], i: [{1}], G_Loss[{2:.8f}], D_Loss[{3:.8f}]".format(epoch, i, batch_loss_G, batch_loss_D)

                    print(msgOut)

            epoch=epoch+1
            sess.run(global_step.assign(epoch))
            saver.save(sess, "params/epoch{0}.ckpt".format(epoch))

            batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [batch_size, z_size]).astype(np.float32)
            voxels = sess.run(x_, feed_dict={z:batch_z})

            v = voxels[0].reshape([32, 32, 32]) > 0
            util.save_binvox(v, "out/epoch{0}.vox".format(epoch), 32)
```

I also update the global step variable using assign at the bottom. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original code was wrong for several reasons because I was trying so many things. The first responder Alexandre Passos gives a valid point, but I believe what changed the game was also the use of scopes (maybe?).

Below is the working updated code if it helps anyone:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# more imports


def extract_number(f): # used to get latest checkpint file
    s = re.findall("epoch(\d+).ckpt",f)
    return (int(s[0]) if s else -1,f)

def restore(sess, saver): # called to restore or just initialise model


    list = glob(os.path.join("./params/e*"))

    if list:

        file = max(list,key=extract_number)

        saver.restore(sess, file[:-5])
        return saver, True, sess

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)

    return saver, False , sess


batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.0001
beta1 = 0.5
z_size = 100
save_interval = 1

data = dataset.read()

total_batch = data.train.num_examples / batch_size

def fill_queue():
    for i in range(int(total_batch*epochLimit)):
        sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict={batch: data.train.next_batch(batch_size)}) # runnig in seperate thread to feed a FIFOqueue



with tf.variable_scope("glob"):
    global_step = tf.get_variable(name='global_step', initializer=0,trainable=False)

# build models

epochLimit = 51

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    saver,rstr,sess = restore(sess, saver)



    with tf.variable_scope("glob", reuse=True):
        epocht = tf.get_variable(name='global_step', trainable=False, dtype=tf.int32)

    epoch = epocht.eval()


    while epoch < epochLimit:

        total_batch = data.train.num_examples / batch_size

        for i in range(int(total_batch)):

            sys.stdout.flush()

            voxels = newData.eval()

            batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [batch_size, z_size]).astype(np.float32)

            sess.run(opt_G, feed_dict={z:batch_z, train:True})
            sess.run(opt_D, feed_dict={input:voxels, z:batch_z, train:True})


            with open("out/loss.csv", 'a') as f:
                batch_loss_G = sess.run(loss_G, feed_dict={z:batch_z, train:False})
                batch_loss_D = sess.run(loss_D, feed_dict={input:voxels, z:batch_z, train:False})
                msgOut = "Epoch: [{0}], i: [{1}], G_Loss[{2:.8f}], D_Loss[{3:.8f}]".format(epoch, i, batch_loss_G, batch_loss_D)

                print(msgOut)

        epoch=epoch+1
        sess.run(global_step.assign(epoch))
        saver.save(sess, "params/epoch{0}.ckpt".format(epoch))

        batch_z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [batch_size, z_size]).astype(np.float32)
        voxels = sess.run(x_, feed_dict={z:batch_z})

        v = voxels[0].reshape([32, 32, 32]) > 0
        util.save_binvox(v, "out/epoch{0}.vox".format(epoch), 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sess.run(init_op)` after restoring this resets all variables to their initial values. Comment that line out and things should work.